# ORDER BY most rows found in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, 1 called googleimage and 1 called googleimagefound, googleimagefound has thousands of rows and each row has an image_id column which corresponds to its respective image from googleimage table (id), each image from the googleimage table could have thousands of rows corresponding to it from the googleimagefound table.

What i am trying to do is SELECT all the images from googleimage table and then ORDER it by the amount of rows found in the googleimagefound table.

Example,

googleimage table has 3 rows with the id's 1, 2, 3

googleimagefound table has 100 rows, 50 of them have the image_id 1, 20 of them have the image_id, 2, and 30 of them have the image_id 3

I want to say

```
SELECT * FROM googleimage ORDER BY most rows found in googleimagefound table where id = googleimagefound.image_id
```

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
SELECT g.*,T1.Found
FROM googleimage g JOIN
(SELECT image_id,COUNT(image_id) as Found
 FROM googleimagefound
 GROUP BY image_id) T1 ON g.image_id=T1.image_id
ORDER BY T1.Found DESC
```

Result will be like:

```
id     name    others     Found
--------------------------------
1      NameA   Value1     120
5      NameD   Value4     95
3      NameB   Value2     82
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that:

```
SELECT count(distinct f.image_id) as mostrowsfound
, i.* FROM googleimage as i
 LEFT JOIN googleimagefound as f ON i.id = f.image_id
 GROUP BY i.id
 ORDER BY mostrowsfound DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join on an aggregate query from `googleimagefound` that counts the rows per id:

```
SELECT    g.*
FROM      googleimage g
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   image_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     googleimagefound
           GROUP BY image_id) gf ON gf.image_id = g.id
ORDER BY  COALESCE(cnt, 0) DESC
```

Comment: How can i get a count from this so i cant test if it works? meaning if i loop over the mysql_fetch_assoc, how can i echo out the count that this query is ordered by for each row

Comment: @user3439600 Just add the `cnt` column to the `select` list: `SELECT g.*, cnt FROM ...`. Then, you can treat `cnt` like any normal column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM googleimage i
  LEFT
  JOIN googleimagefound f
    ON f.image_id = i.image_id
 GROUP
    BY i.image_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(f.image_id) DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Strawberry, please consider adding some description of your query in your answer.